# Android Wear detect if watch has Ambient Screen Mode enabled

Tags: android, wear-os, watch-face-api

Certain Android watches [have the option to turn Ambient Screen Mode on/off](http://www.droid-life.com/2014/09/08/moto-360-ambient-screen-mode/), meaning whether if after brief inactivity the watch will go into ambient mode instead of the screen turning totally off.

Is there any way on the API to detect what is the state of this option on the watch? And just to make it clear, I am not asking on detecting whether if the watch is on ambient mode at any given moment, but to whether if this option is enabled on the watch. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no API to give you that information. What is the usecase you have in mind?

Comment: I am designing a watch face that changes over time, depending how often you check the time. Accounting for this inside the `onAmbientChanged()` method would not work for the cases when the user has Ambient Screen Mode off, because it doesn't get triggered. My workaround will most likely be listening for `Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON` and `OFF`...

Answer (score 0):

The config is saved in `Settings.Secure.DOZE_ENABLED`